# Flex Framework that Uses Signals and Slots

Tags: apache-flex, frameworks, signals-slots

Is there a framework for Flex that uses the Qt Signal and Slots paradigm?

I'm getting tired of these event-mapped frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Penner wrote an AS3 Signals library, to replace flash events.

http://flashblog.robertpenner.com/2009/09/my-new-as3-event-system-signals.html

http://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals

(it's pretty awesome)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PureMVC?